# how to delete file in asp.net mvc using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, web

my script

```
$("#btnDelete").click(function () {
    $.post(url, { fileName: _fileNameAttachementPhoto }, function (data) {
        $("#ResumePart4").html(data);
    });
});
```

my controllers

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string fileName)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
    if (file.Exists) {
        file.Delete();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("DeleteConfirmed");
}
```

I tried do this but nothing happened.

Comment: please add DeleteConfirmed Get Action. PLease check URL also

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 $.post('@Url.Action("DeleteConfirmed", "ControllerName")',
            {
                fileName: FileName
            });
```